# Selecting the difference of sum of a column from one table and sum of a column from another table

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables income and expenses. I have to calculate the sum of expenses and incomes and calculate the difference of both the sums.

I am using

```
SELECT (SUM(a.Amount)-(SELECT SUM(i.Amount) 
FROM incomes i GROUP BY i.UserId)) Expense,
a.UserId FROM amount a GROUP BY a.UserId
```

At present there is only on UserId in income table, so when I execute the query, it is taking the sum of that UserId's Income and subtracting everyone's expenses.

I need their individual difference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subselect

```
SELECT (q.Amount - q.Expense) AS `diff` FROM
(
(SELECT (SUM(a.Amount) 
FROM amount a GROUP BY a.UserId) AS `Amount`,
(SELECT SUM(i.Amount) 
FROM incomes i GROUP BY i.UserId) AS Expense,
) q
```

OR with join

```
SELECT (q.Amount - q.Expense) AS `diff` FROM
(
SELECT SUM(a.Amount)  AS `Amount` ,SUM(i.Amount) AS `Expense`
FROM amount 
 JOIN   incomes i ON ( a.UserId=i.UserId)
GROUP BY i.UserId
) q
```

Or you can try FULL OUTER JOIN as they don't exist but still you can do the same by using UNION

```
SELECT (q.Amount - q.Expense) AS `diff` FROM
(
(SELECT (SUM(a.Amount) AS `Amount` , NULL AS `Expense`
FROM amount a GROUP BY a.UserId) 
UNION ALL
(SELECT NULL AS `Amount`, SUM(i.Amount) AS Expense
FROM incomes i GROUP BY i.UserId) 
) q
```